# How do I get summ in Linq query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, summary

The models are:

```
public class Word
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<UsedCount> UsedCount { get; set; }
}

public class UsedCount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

There is the list of languages:

```
// Actually there are more then 3 langs used
List<string> langList = new List<string> { "en", "pl", "de" };
```

And the list of words

```
List<Word> words = new List<Words>();
```

I count how much times each word used in each languages.
I need to get all words used more then 100 times in total, doesn't matter in which language:

```
renewingIteration = Words.Where(p => (
    p.UsedCount.FirstOrDefault(count => count.Key == langList[0]).Value +
    p.UsedCount.FirstOrDefault(count => count.Key == langList[1]).Value +
    p.UsedCount.FirstOrDefault(count => count.Key == langList[2]).Value 
    //... and so on
    > 100)
```

How can I make it simpler and escape writing langList[0], langList[1]... manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Words.Where(p => p.UsedCount.Sum(u => u.Value) > 100)
```

Would seem to be what you're looking for, assuming that you don't explicitly need to exclude all but the first entry for each language.

Note that there's little point using `FirstOrDefault( ).Value` over `First( ).Value` - the latter will actually throw a more meaningful exception.